# Using for loops in awk to print data

Tags: awk

This is my original input :

```
Feb 27 15:26:22 ::ffff:127.0.0.1 admin@192.168.1.1 (35) /console/login | [Authentication] [User] [LoginFailed] Remote authentication failed. UserName = admin
```

This is the end result I want :

```
Feb 27 14:42:50  [Authentication] [User] [LoginFailed] Remote authentication failed. UserName = admin
```

This is how I do it with sed :

```
cat audit.log | grep -i loginfailed  | grep -i remote | sed 's/::.*\ |//' | less -S
```

My question is how can I do the same thin with awk ?

I've looked at the available solutions but it seems they cannot produce the desired output in the end.

Just to clarify I'm interested in any sort of loop, for example, I want to be able to print from the first to the third and from the 9 to the nth element on a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do it on this way:

```
awk '{ $4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""; print}' input_file
```

if you want to strip those spaces you can use

```
awk '{ $4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""; print}' input_file|sed 's/      / /g'
```

or using only `awk`

```
awk '{ $4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""; gsub(/  /, "", $0);print}' input_file
```